# How Newtonsoft.Json JsonTextReader- used to check if the json-stream is valid

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

Need to process a large JSON file. For Optimize Memory Usage [use](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Performance.htm) bellow syntax, Looking for a way to check the input JSON is valid or input stream is a JSON before execution method reader.Read() because after execution invalid JSON this syntax throws an exception here.

*Exception:
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: h. Path '', line 0, position 0.'*

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

using (Stream s = client.GetStreamAsync("http://www.test.com/large.json").Result)
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s))
using (JsonReader reader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
{
    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();

    // read the json from a stream
    // json size doesn't matter because only a small piece is read at a time from the HTTP request
    while (reader.Read())//invalid json throws exception
      Person p = serializer.Deserialize<Person>(reader);
}
```

Comment: Have you considering simply `catch`ing the exception?

Comment: You can wrap in your code in try catch block